# Addition of two chars produces int

Tags: c++, integer, integer-overflow, integer-promotion

I've made a simple program and compiled it with GCC 4.4/4.5 as follows:

```
int main ()
{
  char u = 10;
  char x = 'x';
  char i = u + x;

  return 0;
}
```

g++ -c -Wconversion a.cpp

And I've got the following:

```
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:5:16: warning: conversion to ‘char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value
```

The same warning I've got for the following code:

```
  unsigned short u = 10;
  unsigned short x = 0;
  unsigned short i = u + x;

a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:5:16: warning: conversion to ‘short unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may alter its value
```

Could anyone please explain me why addition of two chars (or two unsigned shorts) produces int? 
Is it a compiler bug or is it standard compliant?

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if there is some compiler optimisation going on here whereby the 'u' in your addition is just getting substituted with the literal value 10. However that seems rather buggy and non-standards-compiant.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What you're seeing is the result of the so-called "usual arithmetic conversions" that occur during arithmetic expressions, particularly those that are binary in nature (take two arguments).

This is described in §5/9:

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result. This pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*, which are defined as follows:
>
> — If either operand is of type `long double`, the other shall be converted to`long double`.
>   — Otherwise, if either operand is `double`, the other shall be converted to `double`.
>   — Otherwise, if either operand is `float`, the other shall be converted to `float`.
>   — Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both operands.<sup>54)</sup>
>   — Then, if either operand is `unsigned long` the other shall be converted to `unsigned long`.
>   — Otherwise, if one operand is a `long int` and the other `unsigned int`, then if a `long int` can represent all the values of an `unsigned int`, the `unsigned int` shall be converted to a `long int`; otherwise both operands shall be converted to `unsigned long
>    int`.
>   — Otherwise, if either operand is `long`, the other shall be converted to `long`.
>   — Otherwise, if either operand is `unsigned`, the other shall be converted to `unsigned`.
>
> [Note: otherwise, the only remaining case is that both operands are `int`]

The promotions alluded to in §4.5 are:

> 1 An rvalue of type `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `short int`, or `unsigned short int`can be converted to an rvalue of type `int` if `int` can represent all the values of the source type; otherwise, the source rvalue can be converted to an rvalue of type `unsigned int`.
>
> 2 An rvalue of type `wchar_t` (3.9.1) or an enumeration type (7.2) can be converted to an rvalue of the first of the following types that can represent all the values of its underlying type: `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, or `unsigned long`.
>
> 3 An rvalue for an integral bit-field (9.6) can be converted to an rvalue of type `int` if `int` can represent all the values of the bit-field; otherwise, it can be converted to `unsigned int` if `unsigned int` can represent all the values of the bit-field. If the bit-field is larger yet, no integral promotion applies to it. If the bit-field has an enumerated type, it is treated as any other value of that type for promotion purposes.
>
> 4 An rvalue of type `bool` can be converted to an rvalue of type `int`, with `false` becoming zero and `true` becoming `one`.
>
> 5 These conversions are called integral promotions.

From here, sections such as "**Multiplicative operators**" or "**Additive operators**" all have the phrase: "*The usual arithmetic conversions are performed...*" to specify the type of the expression.

In other words, when you do integral arithmetic the type is determined with the categories above. In your case, the promotion is covered by §4.5/1 and the type of the expressions are `int`.

Comment: Yes, thanks. However I thought that §4.5/1 says "can be converted", not "must"... Does it mean that other C++ compiers may produce char, not int?

Comment: @Roman: What it's saying is "this type can become this other type" as a definitive statement (a requirement), then it calls the act of actually making that conversion "integral promotions". So when it says "perform integral promotions", you know `char` will be promoted to an `int` (or `unsigned int`) because, as it demanded, it *is* convertible to such a type ("can be").

Comment: Thanks, I see. But it looks like it is useful for compiler developers, not for other developers (for me, for example). To avoid this warning I need to write something like this: char res = char(u + x); Seems not too comfortable.

Comment: @Roman: It has rationale behind it. Why do you want the to be a `char`?

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter whether it is char or unsigned short. The point is I've got some legacy code which uses arrays of small integer types. So for example addition of two arrays leads to the warning after I start using GCC 4.4 instead of an old compiler version.

Comment: @Roman: Ah, ye olde legacy code. :) Can't help you there, then.

Comment: Actually I don't want to modify a lot of code just to avoid the warning.

Comment: This warning is really useful to find potential bugs in code, except the described case. There is no doubt that the conversion is standard-compliant, but the question is should a compiler warn in this case or not? If no, I shouldn't modify my code. At the moment I'm trying find any patches or bug reports about the case on gcc.gnu.org. Do you know about such behavior of other compilers?

Comment: @Roman: Yes, this is completely normal and good, it's telling you the conversion might lose data. If you're certain it won't, the correct thing to do is to cast the result (well, more correct is to use a wider data type in the first place). Note correct doesn't mean easy.

Answer (score 5):

When you do any arithmetic operation on `char` type, the result it returns is of  `int` type.

See this:

```
char c = 'A';
cout << sizeof(c) << endl;
cout << sizeof(+c) << endl;
cout << sizeof(-c) << endl;
cout << sizeof(c-c) << endl;
cout << sizeof(c+c) << endl;
```

Output:

> 1
>   4
>   4
>   4
>   4

Demonstration at ideone : http://www.ideone.com/jNTMm

Comment: Yep, and it makes sense when you think about it. Adding two `char`s together could easily overflow the result, but not if the result type is at least twice the width of the original one!

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Yes, that is the rationale behind it. Thanks for mentioning that. :-)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: There's no guarantee that `sizeof(int)>sizeof(char)`. The rationale was (as far as I can see) that addition is done by the CPU, and many RISC CPU's only do full-width addition. You 'd end with a 16 or 32 bits value in a register. Limiting it to `char` width would take an extra operation.

Comment: @Tomalak: Actually I doubt it's because of a potential overflow. After all `int i; sizeof(i+i);` is `4` too, same of `short s; sizeof(s+s)`. I think it's got more to do with operating with `int`s whenever possible (ie when int is large enough) than covering overflow.

Comment: @MatthieuM: Actually the result of `sizeof` there is governed by the platform/implementation.

Comment: @MSalters: I know there's no guarantee of it, but it seems bloody likely. Your explanation is more logical though. I was only really positing how the situation _makes sense_, not necessarily _why_ it was made that way.

Comment: @Thomalak: I agree, it is not at all mandated by the standard (but it is permitted), it is simply a liberty that compilers can take to optimize operations.

Answer (score 3):

when you are adding these two characters with each other they are first being promoted to int.

**The result of an addition is an rvalue which is implicitly promoted to
type int if necessary, and if an int can contain the resulting value.
This is true on any platform where sizeof(int) > sizeof(char).
But beware of the fact that char might be treated as signed char by
your compiler.**

These links can be of further help - [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Type_promotion_in_C-like_languages) and [securecoding](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules)

Comment: What document is describing this behavior? C++ Standard or...? Could you please give a link to it?