# Subtracting two chars and adding them to a string

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() { 
    char s2;
    s2 = '1' - '0';
    std::cout << s2;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << '1' - '0';
    std::cin >> s2;
}
```

The output produced is:

```
☺
1
```

My question is, why are the two lines different? I expected and wanted both results to be `1`. By my understanding they should be the same but that is obviously wrong, could somebody please explain this to me? Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why are the two lines different?

The type of the first expression (`s2`) is `char`. The type of the second (`'1' - '0'`) is `int`.

This is why they are rendered differently even though they have the same numeric value, `1`. The first is displayed as [ASCII 1](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-codes/start-of-header-ascii-code-1.gif), whereas the second is displayed as the number 1.

If you are wondering why `'1' - '0'` gives an `int`, see [Addition of two chars produces int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814668/addition-of-two-chars-produces-int)

Comment: how do I get the char (s2) to be the char `'1'`?

Comment: @197: Add `'0'` to it. Or, if it's just for output, cast it to `int`.

Comment: @197 You cast it to `int`.

Comment: @197: Use `+s2`, `int(s2)`, `static_cast<int>(s2)`, or `(int)s2`.

Comment: @JonPurdy Ok I'll go with `(int)s2`.

Comment: @197 Wrong choice... `static_cast<int>(s2)` is safer.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Oh ok cool I'll use that. Would you care to explain why it's safer?

Comment: @197 If you decided to use the C syntax `(int)` in other situations, it could ignore `const`ness; get used to using `static_cast` instead,

Comment: Technically, the first is displayed as whatever-your-system-usesfor-its-character-encoding 1. That's **usually** ASCII, but it's not required to be, and there are systems where it's not.

Answer (score 1):

s2 is char, '1'-'0' is int.

so it types the char value of 1 which is the smile, and 1 for the int value.

Answer (score 1):

Type of s2 is `char`, `std::cout << s2` will call `std::ostream::operator<<(char)` to echo a ASCII character 1 (smile);

'1' - '0' is interpreted as a int value, so `std::ostream::operator<<(int)` will be called and  integer 1 will be printed.