# Why is "int sum=ch1+ch2+ch2" not giving overflow when right-side operands are character variables & result >255?

Tags: c, casting, expression, integer-promotion

In this program I am attempting to assign the result of the addition of character variables to an integer variable.I have made sure that the size of the addition is greater than 255.So I expect an expression overflow on the right and even though the result is 362,due to overflow I expect **106** to be assigned after the result is cast to `int`,not **362**.But strangely **362** is being assigned.

The result is the same irrespective of whether the characters are signed or unsigned.Why is there no overflow and **362**  being assigned?Since there is no integer on the right side during addition and all operands are characters,I don't expect them to be promoted to  `int`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

unsigned char ch1='z',ch2='x'; //Same result for signed too
int sum=ch1+ch2+ch2;
printf("%d",sum);

}
```

Comment: @devnull My lvalue is of `int` type,not unsigned char.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4814901/2235132 for more on arithmetic conversions.

Comment: Read this: [**Addition of two chars produces int**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814668/addition-of-two-chars-produces-int?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: `int` can usually store values >= –2,147,483,648 and < 2,147,483,647. Why do you expect it to overflow for a value > 255?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all calculation starts minimum at integer precision so your statement will work like following

```
int sum=(int)ch1+(int)ch2+(int)ch2;
```