# Operator Overloading of + in C++

Tags: c++, string, char, operator-overloading, string-concatenation

I was recently playing with strings, and I have come across a strange issue. During Operator overloading with + for String concatenation. I have tried to overload with two chars to a string. It returns me a peculiar behaviour.

```
string a = 'den';
a+='e'+'r';
```

I expect the result to be ***dener***. But,it returns ***den╫***. I like to know, what went wrong my approach.
It works when, I tried it separate line, like below.

```
string a = 'den';
a+='e';
a+='r';
```

I got answer from a different question. But, I am repeating here, for anywork around to solve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of two chars in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471235/sum-of-two-chars-in-c-c)

Comment: The `char` type in C++ is essentially an integer. When you write `'e'+'r'`, it's performing integer addition.

Comment: The expression `'e' + 'r'` produces an integer, not a string.

Comment: Multicharacter literal `'den'` is also a integer.

Comment: @Jarod42 typo suspected ... or `a` wouldn't (probably) be "den╫".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a+='e'+'r';
```

There are two operators involved. By their association rules, they work in the following order:

1. `'e'+'r'` is computed
2. `a += result#1` is computed.

About 1.: this is the sum of two objects of type `char`, and it happends that their sum on your system is `╫`<sup>1</sup>.

Finally, `std::string::operator+=` is invoked and `╫` is appended to your string.

What you really want is one of the following:

```
a += "er";
// or
a += 'e';
a += 'r';
// or
for (char c : your_char_array) {
    a += c;
}
// or
a += your_char_array;
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> If you were on an ASCII OS, as [`'e'` is 101 (decimal)](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/lowercase-letter-e-minuscule-ascii-code-101.html) and [`'r'` is 114 (decimal)](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/lowercase-letter-r-minuscule-ascii-code-114.html), their sum is [215 (decimal) which stands for `'Î'` in extended ASCII](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/letter-i-circumflex-accent-ascii-code-215.html).

Comment: Oh, I forgot that point! Thanks @YSC ! Is there any workaround for this to concatenate multiple char with String?

Answer (score -1):

You are adding two characters which are numbers. `'e' + 'r'` is computed first and since 'e' is 101 in ASCII and 'r' is 114 you are concatenating the character with the code 215. To concatenate "er":

```
string a = "den";
a += 'e';
a += 'r';
```

Comment: didnt downvote, though your answer fails to explain why `a += 'e';` works as expected while `a += 'e' + 'r';` does not. 'e' is 101 in ASCII no matter if you write `a += 'e';` or `a += 'e' + 'r';`