# Addition of two character literals in c++

Tags: c++, character, literals, addition

When I write the following code the output is 110. Can anyone tell me why I get that value?

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << '9' + '5';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: there are no strings in your code btw

Comment: You are passing 9 and 5 as a string so it is giving result accordingly

Comment: @Exterminator Those are character literals, not strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of two chars in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471235/sum-of-two-chars-in-c-c)

Comment: @NathanOliver I think your "fix" made it more confusing.

Comment: @Slava How so?  All I did was make the words express what the OP was doing

Comment: @NathanOliver but the problem is OP wanted to do different thing - he wanted to concatenate 2 strings and subject clearly showed that. You reverse engineered his subject so it is not clear what OP really wanted.

Comment: @Slava Probably, but the OP never said that and nothing I removed alluded to that.  If that is what the OP wants you should ask them to clarify that.

Comment: @NathanOliver "but the OP never said that" he actually did by the subject and you removed that.

Comment: @Slava If you want to fix it and add words to the OP's mouth go ahead.  I'm not going to do that.

Comment: I think OP can do that by himself. @krishna if you wanted to concatenate 2 strings you should revert the subject and clearly say that in the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [ASCII encoding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) the values of `'9'` and `'5'` is `57` and `53` (respectively).

`57 + 53` is equal to `110`.

What you're adding is the *encoded* values of the characters, not their digits.

And you get the output `110` (instead of the ASCII character `'n'` which have the value `110`) because the addition causes the characters to be [*promoted*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) to `int` values and the result is an `int` value that is *not* converted to a `char`.

Comment: "instead of the ASCII character 'n'" I think OP expects to get string "95" as a result, not character

Comment: @Slava I know, but I mean that `110` is `'n'`.

Comment: I see, but I got is as OP wanted to get `n` and he is asking why 110 instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html), the value of `9` is 57, and the value of `5` is 53. 57 + 53 is 110. You're adding those chars, so they get promoted to `int`, and if you pass an `int` like this, it gets printed as an int.

What you probably wanted is

```
std::cout << '9' << '5';
```

to print `95`. Or

```
std::cout << 9 + 5;
```

to print `14`.

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII value of `9` is 57 and of `5` is 53. So 57 + 53 equals 110.

[image]

There is no addition for characters, you're adding their ascii value . If you will cast the result to char, the result should be `n` .

Answer (score 0):

That's because char's are represented in ASCII(usually as per suggested on the comments).

Literal '9' is 57 and literal '5' is 53. Thus their sum is 110 which is the literal 'm'.

Comment: `char`s do not have to be ASCII.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am unaware of an implementation that doesn't. Although, I am really curious what the standard says

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thank you for that link!

Answer (score 0):

The is no `char operator+(char, char)`, but there is `int operator+(int, int)`. Hence it converts `'9'` and `'5'` to ints 57 and 53 respectively first and then does the addition, which result is `int` 110.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the original title, it's possible that the OP's intent was to concatenate two string numbers together. If so, this should achieve that.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::string("9") + std::string("5");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With ASCII encoding the values of '9' and '5' is 57 and 53.

57 + 53 is equal to 110.

And the program is returning this value.

If you want program to return the addition of 9 and  5 the you have to write following syntax :-

cout<<9+5;