# template sum function freezes for char

Tags: c++, templates, char

```
#include <iostream>  // std::cout

template <class T>
T Sum(T x, T y) {
  return x + y;
}
int main() {
  std::cout << Sum<int>(5, 10);
  std::cout << "\n" << 'a' + 'b';
  std::cout << "\n" << Sum<char>('a', 'b');
  return 0;
}
```

The program freezes on the last line when using [cpp.sh site](http://cpp.sh/5squ), can somebody please explain why?

Comment: What do you expect this to output?

Comment: Please explain why you mean the "program freezes".

Comment: which compiler? Works for [clang and gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/9jpHpR). It there is no reason to freeze. Works on [msvc too](https://rextester.com/LBIQ45755).

Comment: The compiler can deduce the type. You may use `Sum('a', 'b')`.

Comment: To be clear by "it works" I meant it doesn't freeze as OP describes the problem.

Comment: @MarekR I checked in online C++ shell http://cpp.sh/ and g++

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. same as the second line. Second line outputs 195

Comment: Ok so this is problem of this site not your code.

Comment: @WernerHenze programs runs and never terminates. In online shell http://cpp.sh/ it's showing "rinning"

Comment: @Mar "not your code" let's be clear, the code likely has undefined behavior.

Comment: @DoehJohn this is bug of this site. Most probably it expects UTF-8 encoding in output and your program prints a character which says there will be continuation of UTF-8 encoded character, but nothing else is printed.

Comment: The second line outputs an integer because `'a'+'b'` has type `int`. `Sum<char>('a', 'b')` has type `char`. These are different things and you cannot expect them to work the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming signed 8 bit `char`, which is very common, adding `'a'` and `'b'` and storing the result in a `char` overflows and causes undefined behavior. Thus, the program is free to do anything. In my [testing](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7awUPh) with GCC it prints some garbage and `main` exits with `0`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ayxan already pointed out, adding two `char`s and storing the result in a char is not a good idea, you can change the return type of your function to `auto` as the operation`char` + `char` returns `int` (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19471301/8359552)). Simply write

```
template <class T> auto Sum(T x, T y)
{
    std::cout << sizeof(x) << " " << sizeof(y) << " " << sizeof(x+y) << std::endl;;
    return x + y;
}
```

Running your main will output:

```
4 4 4
15
195
1 1 4
195
```

See the [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/DX_SQf).

Comment: he written that application hangs on last line. So this is not the problem.

Comment: @MarekR You're right, I haven't read carefully enough that he was only looking for an explanation and not a fix. I'll still leave this here, maybe it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is site you used for testing.
As I showed in comment your code doesn't hangs on:

- [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/y4Vi3P) with gcc or clang
- [rextester.com](https://rextester.com/LBIQ45755) with msvc

Problem is on site [cpp.sh site](http://cpp.sh/5squ).

Most probably this site is configured to assume UTF-8 encoding in application output.
Now when you do addition of `char` characters are promoted to `int` that is why `195` is printed in earlier line. Your `Sum` clips this results to `char` type (here is undefined behavior since there is integer overflow).

Now in UTF-8 this byte `195` represents is an indicator that current character is build from two bytes. Your program never sends next byte. This site should be able to handle malformed UTF-8 and noticed that stream has ended and not wait for next character. It waits for this character and as a result it hangs. So this is a bug of site `cpp.sh`.