# why does this return a number and what does that number mean?

Tags: c++

I want to print the first and last characters of a word next to each other, by indexing the string and concatenating the characters together. I tried this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string text = "ASCII";
    cout << text[0] + text[text.length()-1]; 
}
```

But instead of the expected output of `AI`, I get `138`. If I try using different indices into `text`, the numeric value changes.

Why do I get a number instead of a string? What does the number mean?

Comment: Addition will produce an `int` result by converting the individual `char` operands to `int` first.

Comment: If you wanted to output two characters then `cout << text[0] << text[text.length()-1];` would be the way to do that.

Comment: Replace `+` with `<<`.  Unlike other languages, C++ doesn't support universal concatenation.

Comment: `char` is an integral type. The sum 'A' + 'I' is promoted to `int`.

Comment: The numeric ASCII code for `A` is 65, and for `I` is 73, so you end up with `65 + 73 = 138` (not `148` like you claim).

Comment: There is the tricky business of _integral promotion_... At CppReference, scroll down to the the heading [Integral Promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion), and you will see: _prvalues of small integral types (such as `char`) may be converted to prvalues of larger integral types (such as `int`). In particular, arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than `int` as arguments, and integral promotions are automatically applied after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable._

Comment: Characters have numeric (integral) values.   Adding two characters adds the numeric values, and produces a numeric value.   It doesn't create a string by appending the two characters.

Comment: Dupe: [Sum of two chars in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471235/sum-of-two-chars-in-c-c)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of two chars in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471235/sum-of-two-chars-in-c-c)

Comment: You can create a temporary string `std::string {text[0]}`

Answer (score 2):

**The problem:**

In this expresion:

```
text[0] + text[text.length()-1]
```

`text[0]` and `text[text.length()-1]` are both of type `char`.

C++ dos not support concatenation of 2 `char`s using `operator+` (as you seem to expect).
Instead both are **promoted** to `int` (using their ASCII values) and added as integers.
The ASCII of `'A'` (`text[0]`) is 65 and of `'I'` (`text[text.length()-1]`) is 71 and therefore the output should be `138` (not 148 as you suggested in your question before it was edited) - see [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dreTEWsEv).

**A solution:**

In order to fix it you can further use `ostream` `operator<<` to concatenate the `char`s:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string text = "ASCII";
    std::cout << text[0] << text[text.length() - 1];
}
```

**Output:**

```
AI
```

[Live demo - Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nv8c6Ms33)

**A side note:**
Better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

The key to the problem is that char can be converted to number, and adding two chars can be interpreted as adding two numbers together.

text[0] for 'A' to number: 65.

text[text.length() -1] for 'I' is expressed as a number: 73

So you get 138

Comment: By the way: Your code won't compile.

Comment: Not "_can be_", _will be_.  It is a matter of expected operand types of `+` and the fact that it is an arithmetic operator, not a string concatenation operator (in this context).